# Shorthand/implicit if() statement with no if

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

JavaScript/jQuery code found in a Smarty template:

```js
( $( 'carriercode' ) && $( 'carriercode' ).value == '' )
{
    alert( 'Please select Shipping Carrier Code' );
    return false;
}
```

This isn't so much a problem as a curiosity.

Question 1: I've never seen this construction before. It appears to work exactly like an `if()` statement, but without the `if` keyword. Is this valid/standard/reliably supported?

Question 2: the jQuery selector is looking for the `carriercode` tag, which obviously isn't part of standard HTML. Is this a feature of Smarty, or just lazy developers making up new tags? Again, is it valid (in Smarty), standard practice, and will it work reliably?

Related: I did a minimal test in a simple HTML page (below), which works but isn't valid markup. I'm curious whether it would work reliably in different environments. I always follow standards when writing my own code, but sometimes it's not practical to go in and fix up all the code when joining an existing project.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en-gb'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script>
            //<![CDATA[
            ( $( 'test' ) && $( 'test' ).value === 'test' )
            {
                alert( 'test!' );
            }
            //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Test</p>
        <test value='test'></test>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been unable to find out much about either of these questions by searching the internet, searching for `if` tends to return a lot of results about JavaScript for beginners which might be swamping answers to more esoteric cases like this. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: `$( 'carriercode' )` is always truthy so that check is useless

Comment: Try this experiment: Delete the `<test>` element. Do you still get an alert?

Comment: If smary is a templating engine, then it can do whatever it wants with the syntax, since it will be able to introduce a completely new syntax. This code is not valid JS code, though. It will *run* without throwing an error but it will not act as if you've replaced the `if` - the code inside the curly braces will *always run* regardless of the previous line that looks like a condition. In JS the two are completely unrelated - on one line you do some truthy checks and boolean logic but the result is discarded and the next lines are run.

Comment: There's no `if` happening here; it's an expression (immediately thrown away) followed by a block. If the `{` was on the same line as the expr it's likely a syntax error, but haven't checked. Non-standard HTML tags will (should, anyway) be found, but jQuery doesn't return falsey if nothing is found. So it's wrong on multiple levels. Smarty is not involved here; it will not do anything since the JS in question isn't Smarty code.

Comment: I too have never seen code structured as that, but can confirm that the code will _always_ run no matter the intended condition. This is true for the language itself. That templating _could_ be doing something else, but I suspect this is just bad code... https://jsfiddle.net/rkxas3bq/

Comment: @VLAZ It's perfectly *valid*, just pointless.

Comment: @DaveNewton I meant that it doesn't do what OP thinks it does. So it's not a valid `if` statement.

Comment: FWIW: questions like this are trivially self-answerable by breaking it down and seeing what happens at each step and varying the input conditions, and would have likely been faster.

Comment: Oh, one more thing comments haven't mentioned yet - `$('selector).value` will not give the value property of the element with tag `selector` - you need `.val()` for that. Reading `.value` will return `undefined` as that property does not exist on the jQuery object.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions as one, we strive for focused questions at StackOverflow so you they can have a clear answer that is helpful to others

Comment: Thank you all for your insight. It was very helpful. I am putting an answer to this question based on your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarising the helpful answers that were provided in comments, plus a bit more info:

1. Omitting the `if` on the conditional statement just means that the result is thrown away after evaluation. In other words, this is a bug.
2. Confusingly, the codebase where I found this code uses both jQuery and Prototype.js, both of which use the `$()` construct by default. `$( 'test' ) && $( 'test' ).value === 'test'` is valid Prototype.js, and it's looking for an element with an `id` of `#test`. This is by contrast to jQuery, where to look for an `id` it must be prefixed by `#` in the selector. In fact this codebase was using jQuery's `noConflict()` to avoid use of `$()` because it would interfere with Prototype.js.
3. jQuery selectors work on **any** element name, not just ones that are valid in HTML.
4. I should do more testing before asking questions. Thanks again to the commenters for their help and patience!